# Export Loops to CSV - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, export-to-csv

I have a script that takes properties of schedules from two directories and writes the output to the host. I want to capture this output into a csv. So far the script writes all attributes to the host correctly, but the csv only has the headers, i.e "Name" and "Path".

Here is what I have:

```
$results = @()
$JobObjects = $SchedulerObject.Search("/TradeSupport/Objects/Schedules/","*",65535,"*",$true);
foreach($JobObject in $JobObjects){
$Schedules = $JobObject.getabatobject();
foreach ($Schedule in $Schedules){
write-host("Name :" + $Schedule.Name)
write-host("Path :" + $Schedule.Path)

    $details = @{
            Name = $ScheduleObjects.Name
            Path = $ScheduleObjects.FullPath
            }}}

$JobObjects2 = $SchedulerObject.Search("/Operations/Objects/Schedules/","*",65535,"*",$true);
foreach($JobObject2 in $JobObjects2){
$Schedules2 = $JobObject2.getabatobject();
foreach ($Schedule2 in $Schedules2){
write-host("Name :" + $Schedule2.Name)
write-host("Path :" + $Schedule2.Path)


$details = @{
            Name = $ScheduleObjects2.Name
            Path = $ScheduleObjects2.FullPath
        }}  
    }
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details


$results | select-object -property Name,Path | export-csv -Path \\ch0-craab-01\c$\Support\AB_Reports\Objects_Report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the **$Results** inside the **Foreach** Loops not on the outside

The OP said this didn't work and i took a second look at the script.

The variable the OP is using to save to $results is unique and holds no information.

The correct variables are

```
$Schedule.Name
$Schedule.Name
```

But you are using

```
$ScheduleObjects.Name
$ScheduleObjects.FullPath
```

The below script should now work

```
$results = @()
$JobObjects = $SchedulerObject.Search("/TradeSupport/Objects/Schedules/","*",65535,"*",$true);
foreach($JobObject in $JobObjects){
    $Schedules = $JobObject.getabatobject();
    foreach ($Schedule in $Schedules){
        write-host("Name :" + $Schedule.Name)
        write-host("Path :" + $Schedule.Path)
        $details = @{
            Name = $Schedule.Name
            Path = $Schedule.Path
        }
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
    }
}

$JobObjects2 = $SchedulerObject.Search("/Operations/Objects/Schedules/","*",65535,"*",$true);
foreach($JobObject2 in $JobObjects2){
    $Schedules2 = $JobObject2.getabatobject();
    foreach ($Schedule2 in $Schedules2){
        write-host("Name :" + $Schedule2.Name)
        write-host("Path :" + $Schedule2.Path)
        $details = @{
            Name = $Schedule2.Name
            Path = $Schedule2.Path
        }
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
    }  
}    
$results | select-object -property Name,Path | export-csv -Path \\ch0-craab-01\c$\Support\AB_Reports\Objects_Report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I am currently looking to see if using "Write-Ouput" would work.

Comment: what happened when you did it the way i posted

Comment: No change. It still prints all values to the host, but only prints the headers in the csv.

Comment: you deleted the file from \\ch0-craab-01\c$\Support\AB_Reports\Objects_Report.csv before you ran it right?

Comment: I see your issue

Comment: I do not delete it prior to running. It overwrites the existing file. What are you thinking?

Comment: the fixed scrpt and issue are now edited into the post. Please mark correct if this works for u

Comment: Oh wow, how embarrassing. I guess sometimes you look for a complicated solution and miss the one in front of your face. This works! I very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to see where you go wrong when you indent the code properly to line up with your loops:

```
$results = @()
$JobObjects = $SchedulerObject.Search("/TradeSupport/Objects/Schedules/","*",65535,"*",$true);
foreach($JobObject in $JobObjects) {
    $Schedules = $JobObject.getabatobject();
    foreach ($Schedule in $Schedules){
        write-host("Name :" + $Schedule.Name)
        write-host("Path :" + $Schedule.Path)

        $details = @{
            Name = $ScheduleObjects.Name
            Path = $ScheduleObjects.FullPath
        }
    }
}

$JobObjects2 = $SchedulerObject.Search("/Operations/Objects/Schedules/","*",65535,"*",$true);
foreach($JobObject2 in $JobObjects2) {
    $Schedules2 = $JobObject2.getabatobject();
    foreach ($Schedule2 in $Schedules2) {
        write-host("Name :" + $Schedule2.Name)
        write-host("Path :" + $Schedule2.Path) 

        $details = @{
            Name = $ScheduleObjects2.Name
            Path = $ScheduleObjects2.FullPath
        }
    }  
}
$results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details


$results | select-object -property Name,Path | export-csv -Path \\ch0-craab-01\c$\Support\AB_Reports\Objects_Report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Now you can more easily see that you only ever use your `$details` variable *outside* of the loops. You want to append that item on to your `$results` array on every iteration.